# Synchronized in lambda blocks in JAVA 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Can `synchronized` be used for some of the code blocks written in lambda expression block. With respect to the following code snippet :

```
workflowTasks.forEach((workflowTask) -> {
        String taskName = workflowTask.getTaskName();
        if (profileNames.containsKey(taskName) || newSetDuplication.contains(taskName)) {
            errorMessages.append(taskName + ",");
        }
        newSetDuplication.add(taskName);
    });
```

Comment: The lambda expression block allows all statements an ordinary code block allows too. The bigger question is whether it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Of course!  Your block of code is logically equivalent to the following, assuming `workFlowTask` is of the type `WorkFlowTask`:

```
for (WorkFlowTask workFlowTask : workFlowTasks) {
    String taskName = workflowTask.getTaskName();

    if (profileNames.containsKey(taskName) || newSetDuplication.contains(taskName)) {
        errorMessages.append(taskName + ",");
    }

    newSetDuplication.add(taskName);
}
```

Obviously, the `synchronized` keyword can be used here, although there are many other things to consider before using it, **especially within a loop**.  Your `forEach` lambda is just syntactic sugar for a `Consumer<WorkFlowTask>` anyway, which you can also use `synchronized` with.

Comment: Just to add a small note: `this` in a lambda references the instance of the surrounding class. So, the `synchronized` block in the lambda does not synchronize an instance of the functional interface, which is why using `synchronized` should not have any undesired side effects. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24202272/1482294