# Custom Predicate chaining

Tags: java, java-8

I am learning Java 8 . I am trying to create custom Predicate chaining method as below

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Predicate<T> {

    boolean test(T t);

    default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<T> other){
        return t -> this.test(t) && other.test(t);
    }
}
```

When i define my Predicate as above it works , but if i try to implement the same as below it gives me StackOverflow exception

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Predicate<T> {

    boolean test(T t);

    default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<T> other){
        //return t -> this.test(t) && other.test(t);
        return new Predicate<T>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(T t) {
                return test(t) && other.test(t);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Can you please explain me why it is giving me stackoverflow exception in Java 7 style whereas do not give any exception if i define it using lambda.

Comment: `this` in a lambda doesn&#39;t refer to the lambda. In an anonymous inner class, `this` refers to the instance of the inner class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`test(t)` is a recursive call to itself, since the unqualified call is to the anonymous class.

So would `this.test(t)` be, since `this` refers to the anonymous class.

Change to `Predicate.this.test(t)`

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Predicate<T> {

    boolean test(T t);

    default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<T> other){
        //return t -> this.test(t) && other.test(t);
        return new Predicate<T>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(T t) {
                return Predicate.this.test(t) && other.test(t);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

See [answer to "Lambda this reference in java"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24202272/5221149) for more detail.

Comment: As per your answer this should also not work default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<T> other){
        return t -> this.test(t) && other.test(t);
    }  . But this is working fine . How it is so ?

Comment: @IshantGaurav Because a lambda is not an anonymous class, and it is explained in the link I provided.