# Method call on a Lambda object returns value

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, predicate, functional-interface

the expression `this.apply(stringValue)` returns `true` on a lambda expression `j8Test.PerformChange$$Lambda$2/284720968@2f4d3709`

Why does it return true and not false. And why doest it return actually anything at all? (I am not talking about all other objects of type PerformChangeImpl)

```
private final List<PerformChange> performChangeList = Arrays.asList(
        new PerformChangeImpl("1"),
        new PerformChangeImpl("2"),
        new PerformChangeImpl("3")
);

@FunctionalInterface
interface PerformChange extends Function<String, Boolean> {

    default PerformChange performChange(PerformChange input) {
        System.out.println("1 this: " + this);
        System.out.println("2 input: " + input);
        return stringValue -> {
            System.out.println("\n3 this: " + this);
            System.out.println("4 input: " + input);
            if (this.apply(stringValue)) {
                System.out.println("5 this: " + this);
                return input.apply(stringValue);
            }
            return false;
        };
    }
}

class PerformChangeImpl implements PerformChange {

    private final String value;

    public PerformChangeImpl(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean apply(String string) {
        System.out.println("\n6: " + this);
        System.out.println("7: " + string);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "obj id: " + value;
    }
}
```

and

```
private void executePerformChanges() {
    System.out.println(performChangeList.stream()
            .reduce(PerformChange::performChange)
            .orElse(new PerformChangeImpl("4"))
            .apply("test"));
}
```

result in

```
1 this: obj id: 1
2 input: obj id: 2
1 this: j8Test.PerformChange$$Lambda$2/284720968@2f4d3709
2 input: obj id: 3

3 this: j8Test.PerformChange$$Lambda$2/284720968@2f4d3709
4 input: obj id: 3

3 this: obj id: 1
4 input: obj id: 2

6: obj id: 1
7: test
5 this: obj id: 1

6: obj id: 2
7: test
5 this: j8Test.PerformChange$$Lambda$2/284720968@2f4d3709

6: obj id: 3
7: test
true

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: It seems to be that you’ve been fooled by [the meaning of `this` inside a lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24202272/2711488)…

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
public Boolean apply(String string) {
  ...
```

Your class `PerformChangeImpl` overrides the `apply()` method. That is the core of the `Function` interface.

And in the end, your code calls:

```
.apply("test"))
```

And the very last statement within `apply()` is:

```
return true;
```

The method returns `true`, because you told it to do so. So you should either change that method body to return `true` / `false` based on some condition, or you shouldn't be calling `apply()` in the end.

And note: this becomes really obvious from the print statements. In the end, you get `6` and `7`, which you print within the `apply()` of the `PerformChangeImpl` class.

Also note: your **defaulted** method does:

```
if(this.apply(stringValue)) {
```

That calls `apply()` on the "surrounding" `PerformChangeImpl` ... and will return `true`.

Comment: If you have time check out with breakpoints at this line. My question refers to only one iteration, where there is at least one .apply call on a Lambda expression, not on an object of Type `PerformChangeImpl` and this returns true.

Comment: @AnnaKlein `performChangeList` contains three instances of PerformChangeImpl, and you stream on that. You call apply() on those objects. You keep calling on *those* objects, in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two implementations of `PerformChange`:

1. The class `PerformChangeImpl` which [functional method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html) `apply` always returns `true`. There is no chance to get `false`.
2. The lambda expression `str -> apply(str) && input.apply(str)` which you are generating in `performChange` (I simplified it a bit). There is a chance to get `false` if either `apply(str)` or `input.apply(str)` returns `false`.

Since `performChangeList` contains only `PerformChangeImpl` instances, the generated lambda could be simplified to `input.apply(str)`, In other words, the method would look like

```
default PerformChange performChange(PerformChange input) {
    // str -> apply(str) && input.apply(str)
    // str -> true && input.apply(str)
    // str -> input.apply(str)
    // input::apply
    // input
    return input;
}
```

and the resulting `true` is expected for any given `String` as long as `performChangeList` is populated exclusively with `PerformChangeImpl` objects.

As a side note, `Function<String, Boolean>` is simply `Predicate<String>` and it's better to use the latter.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface PerformChange extends Predicate<String> { ... }

class PerformChangeImpl implements PerformChange {
    @Override
    public boolean test(String string) { ... }
}
```